# Aptana 3 unfolds whole file after detecting eny error in code

Tags: php, eclipse, aptana, folding

Title is quite descriptive: every time Aptana (Studio 3, build: 3.0.8.201201201658) detects error in code, like when there is missing semicolon or something similar, whole code that is in file unfolds.

This is very annoying when working with large files.

Has anyone getting similar bug, anyone knows how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: @10robinho this is quite un-related to your question but if you're writing such large files on PHP I would probably suggest you to look into classes and a model-view-controller approach to your App.

Comment: @Frankie: How does that make files any smaller or code any less foldable?

Comment: @BoltClock I've seen some new developers trying to write full apps on a single file. No code reuse whatsoever. On top of that, PHP and HTML were mixed together in a weird soup of content and program logic. I've actually once seen one of those files that, when called in a special way would serve a text string as a JS file. Obvious all those files where pretty huge. Real messy. So based on the users rep and the question I though it could perhaps (note the may or may not) help to point him in the direction of code-reuse, splitting code and presentation, etc. As a comment, obvious.

Comment: @Frankie: I use MVC, and I want to fold my functions because there are many functions in each file and it looks cleaner for me to build on and repair if everything is folded. But, lets try to stay on topic, nobody knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4061.  Please join the discussion there and add yourself as a watcher of the ticket to get notified when it is fixed.

Thanks.